# Transaction log shipping in different edition of sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

We are considering to upgrade our Database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014. However, The new licensing with Core based seem to be very expensive.

We have one primary database and one secondary database. If we have SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition for the Primary database and SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition for the Secondary Database.

Question 1)
Is it possible to run transaction log shipping in different edition as above?

Question 2)
Could it be possible to run it from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: 1) Yes, assuming the primary doesn't use any Enterprise-only features; log shipping is just backup/restore so if that works then log shipping will work. 2) You will never be able to restore a 2014 database onto a 2008 R2 instance, no. So log shipping is a no-op.

Comment: @AaronBertrand if we have a database on SQL Server 2014 with compatibality level set to 100, will this allow us to use sql server 2008 R2 as secondary database for log shipping?

Comment: @M.Ali No, compatibility level has nothing to do with it. It's about the database engine. You can restore up, but not down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to run transaction log shipping in different edition as above?

Going for possibility yes it is possible to configure log shipping between SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and standard edition. But Just think of scenario where you are using enterprise features in Enterprise edition and failover happens now SQL server is on standrad edition and enterprise features will not work and you might face issue with application, some functionality crashing. I dont think you want this.

Plus again if you are using enterprise features and to configure loghshipping you take backup of enterprise edition and try to restore it on standard it would fail saying the backup has enterprise features and DB cannot be brought online because current database does not supports it

> Could it be possible to run it from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2008 R2?

No because you cannot restore database backup taken on SQL Server 2014 on SQL Server 2008 R2. If you like to make SQL Server 2008 R2 as primary and 2014 as secondary then you may succeed in configuring logshipping using T-SQL scripts( you cannot do it using GUI) but consider scenario where failover occurs and 2014 is new primary you cannot fail it back to 2008 r2 as Higher to lower version is not allowed.

Hope this is clear

Comment: Shanky, Thank you for the answers. We may want to implement those cool new features such as In-Memory OLTP Engine and Column Store Indexes. Which is available in Enterprise Edition. We could have 2014 as secondary.

Comment: Then you have to make sure both version are same.

Comment: Thanks. It was my first time asking questions on Stackoverflow. Therefore, I cannot upvote your comment. I will come back and upvote your comment and others too. Once I earn more reputation :)